# Return unique values that meet a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, having-clause

This query:

```
 Select Distinct 
     User ID,
     Name,
     Status,        
 From Table 1
```

Gives me:

[image: Generic Results]

...but what I am looking for is unique USER IDs which have ONLY ONE "ANI" status, i.e. this...

[image: Desired Results]

A little help please?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, show the data as formatted text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation:

```
select user_id, min(name) as name, min(status) as status
from table1
group by user_id
having count(*) = 1 and min(status) = 'ANI'
```

This filters on `user_id`s that appear only once in the table, and whose status is `'ANI'`.

Comment: i need it more specific to where "ANI" itself only shows up once for any particular user, what adjustments would need to be made?

Comment: @Mo-L: as I understand your comment, this is what the query does already...